# Request for a user directed Crystal Reports front end

Tags: user-interface, crystal-reports-xi

We have a request to design a front end that will be used by the user, to create their own crystal reports. Does Crystal Reports provide this capability - passing the fields needed and then create that report? What I have in mind would be a grid with drill down, showing say customer orders, and sales.

Then for export option you can have one to be a crystal report. SO then, the CR would access the data from the drill down, which would be exported first to a table, then CR accesses that data.

Is this the best way to design this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff you are showing user in the data grid, you can always tell the report to pick data from the table, make sure to design the report according to the stuff you are showing in the grid, after the used is done selecting, just pass the parameters to the report selection formula or either using an sql query, it should work!.